# How to get product details from product barcode in ios application

Tags: ios

I am using ZBar SDK to read barcode. It shows product barcode number. I want product details like name, price, etc. Searching from internet I conclude that I need to use APIs. can anybody write steps if i want to use "http://searchupc.com/" API. in my Application.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: not about programming **within the scope defined in the help center.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, I can write the whole thing for you as well if you like! :P

anyway:

1. see http://searchupc.com/api/ (do soap requests and process soap responses.)
2. oh and get an account at http://searchupc.com/developers/

Comment: disclaimer: JK! not self promotion -- JK